# Why is bulk reading from a Postgres DB in C# taking so long?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

I am performing a bulk read on a Postgres DB in C#.  I am not a database expert by any means, so I suspect I am doing something obviously wrong in my code.  I have attempted 2 methods, and both are really slow.  I am reading ~150K records.  Using method 1, the read took 43 seconds, and using the method 2, the read took 117 seconds.

**Method 1**

```
private const string HeartbeatsQuery = @"SELECT id, client_id AS clientId, run_id AS runId, lat, long, speed, 
                                                     flow_rate_gallon_min AS flowRateGallonMin, cumulative_flow_pulse_count AS CumulativeFlowPulseCount, 
                                                     image, event_date_utc AS eventDateUtc, device_serial_number AS deviceSerialNumber 
                                                FROM heartbeats";

public async Task<List<Heartbeat>> GetHeartbeats(int clientId, Guid runId)
        {
            var query = $@"{HeartbeatsQuery} 
                           WHERE client_id=@clientId AND run_id=@runId
                           ORDER BY event_date_utc";

            using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                var heartbeats = await connection.QueryAsync<Heartbeat>(
                    query,
                    param: new
                    {
                        clientId = clientId,
                        runId = runId
                    });

                return heartbeats?.ToList() ?? new List<Heartbeat>();
            }
        }
```

**Method 2**

```
public async Task<List<Heartbeat>> GetHeartbeats2(int clientId, Guid runId)
        {
            var heartbeats = new List<Heartbeat>();
            using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var reader = await connection.BeginBinaryExportAsync(
                    @$"COPY  (SELECT client_id, run_id, lat, long, speed, flow_rate_gallon_min, cumulative_flow_pulse_count,
                    image, event_date_utc, device_serial_number FROM heartbeats WHERE run_id='{runId}')
                    TO STDOUT (FORMAT BINARY)"))
                {
                    while (await reader.StartRowAsync() > 0)
                    {
                        if (reader.IsNull) await reader.SkipAsync();
                        var heartbeat = new Heartbeat();

                        heartbeat.ClientId = await reader.ReadAsync<int>(NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
                        heartbeat.RunId = await reader.ReadAsync<Guid>(NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Uuid);

                        if (reader.IsNull)
                        {
                            await reader.SkipAsync();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            heartbeat.Lat = await reader.ReadAsync<decimal>(NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Numeric);
                        }

                        if (reader.IsNull)
                        {
                            await reader.SkipAsync();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            heartbeat.Long = await reader.ReadAsync<decimal>(NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Numeric);
                        }

                        if (reader.IsNull)
                        {
                            await reader.SkipAsync();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            heartbeat.Speed = await reader.ReadAsync<decimal>(NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Numeric);
                        }

                        if (reader.IsNull)
                        {
                            await reader.SkipAsync();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            heartbeat.FlowRateGallonMin = await reader.ReadAsync<decimal>(NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Numeric);
                        }

                        if (reader.IsNull)
                        {
                            await reader.SkipAsync();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            heartbeat.CumulativeFlowPulseCount = await reader.ReadAsync<decimal>(NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Bigint);
                        }

                        if (reader.IsNull)
                        {
                            await reader.SkipAsync();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            heartbeat.Image = await reader.ReadAsync<string>(NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text);
                        }

                        if (reader.IsNull)
                        {
                            await reader.SkipAsync();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            heartbeat.EventDateUtc = await reader.ReadAsync<DateTime>(NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.TimestampTz);
                        }

                        if (reader.IsNull)
                        {
                            await reader.SkipAsync();
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            heartbeat.DeviceSerialNumber = await reader.ReadAsync<string>(NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text);
                        }
                        
                        heartbeats.Add(heartbeat);
                    }
                }
            }

            return heartbeats;
        }
```

I was hoping to be able to pull in this data in 1-2 seconds, is that realistic?  Is there a better approach to querying this data?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could also try `QueryUnbufferedAsync` to stream the results. Depending on what you are using the rows for, processing them while fetching may save time.

Comment: You might consider adding an index or two to your database table. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html.

Comment: What part is slow? The database, the query or your code? The second method should be much faster because of COPY. 150k records is not that much, on decent (virtual) hardware that can be done in your target of 1~2 seconds. Most likely faster

Comment: In regards to the second method, are you aware of a way to prevent having to do all the null checking?  Also, this is my current hardware, it's pretty bare bones:  Burstable, B1ms, 1 vCores, 2 GiB RAM, 32 GiB storage